# Uneven spacing between tables

Tags: tables, spacing

I am getting uneven space between this specific table and text in my latex. I cannot understand why. I have searched (tirelessly) for examples that correlate to my problem, but all has been in vain.

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,dvipsnames]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{latexsym,booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[singlespacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref} %% to make the referencing clickable 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption} 
\captionsetup[table]{skip=1pt}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{booktabs}

% Referencing 
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}

%% Copied from repository before to make make comments

\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand{\tb}[1]{\noindent \textcolor{NavyBlue}{\textbf{Tom:}  #1}} % 1 'cause Trom is the best! 
\newcommand{\ish}[1]{\noindent \textcolor{Orange}{\textbf{Ish:}  #1}}


%% For modeling
\usepackage{optidef} % Ugly package, remove this package later. 

\geometry{a4paper,left=2cm,right=2.0cm, top=2cm, bottom=2.0cm}

\newtheorem{Definition}{Definition}
\newtheorem{Theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{Lemma}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{Corollary}{Corollary}
\newtheorem{Proposition}{Proposition}
\newtheorem{Algorithm}{Algorithm}
\numberwithin{Theorem}{section}
\numberwithin{Definition}{section}
\numberwithin{Lemma}{section}
\numberwithin{Algorithm}{section}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}


% *********************************************************************
% Headings and page layout
% *********************************************************************
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % to design my own headings
\usepackage{titlesec, titletoc} % to design my own toc and part/chapter/section styles

% page style of "chapter"
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\LARGE \bfseries}
    {\Large Chapter \thesection \thispagestyle{plain}}{0ex}{\titlerule\vspace{2ex}}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0ex}{-8ex}{8ex}

\titleformat{\section}[display]{\LARGE \bfseries}
    {\thispagestyle{plain}}{0ex}{\titlerule\vspace{2ex}}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0ex}{0ex}{0ex}

\titleformat{\subsection}[display]{\Large \bfseries}
    {\thispagestyle{plain}}{0ex}{\vspace{2ex}}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0ex}{0ex}{3ex}


% definition of headings
\fancypagestyle{memo}{
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[RO,LE]{\thepage}
    \fancyhead[RE]{\rightmark}
    \fancyhead[LO]{\leftmark}
    \renewcommand\headrulewidth{0.5pt}
}


\begin{document}

As a part of the programme mentioned above, delivery models are designed to meet the needs of each group. The table below summarises their delivery model.

\begin{table}[H]
\caption{Delivery model} 
\centering\renewcommand\cellalign{lc}
\setcellgapes{3pt}\makegapedcells
\begin{tabular}{|l| c| l|} \hline 
\textbf{JCVI Priority} & \textbf{Deployment strategy} & \textbf{Estimated finishing date} \\ \hline
1 and 2 & \makecell{Care home residents and staff: Resident homes \\ Over 80 years old: GP surgeries } & 5th Februrary 2021\\
3,4 and 5 & Vaccination appointment & Early March 2021 \\ 
6,7,8 and 9 & Mass vaccination centres & Early May 2021 \\ \hline\end{tabular}
\vspace{-3mm}
\end{table}


The indicates that the vaccinations began in Scotland on 8 January 2021. However, whether the vaccination process began all across Scotland. 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

How about commenting out the `\vspace` at the end of the table?

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,dvipsnames]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{latexsym,booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[singlespacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref} %% to make the referencing clickable 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption} 
\captionsetup[table]{skip=1pt}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{booktabs}

% Referencing 
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}

%% Copied from repository before to make make comments

\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand{\tb}[1]{\noindent \textcolor{NavyBlue}{\textbf{Tom:}  #1}} % 1 'cause Trom is the best! 
\newcommand{\ish}[1]{\noindent \textcolor{Orange}{\textbf{Ish:}  #1}}


%% For modeling
\usepackage{optidef} % Ugly package, remove this package later. 

\geometry{a4paper,left=2cm,right=2.0cm, top=2cm, bottom=2.0cm}

\newtheorem{Definition}{Definition}
\newtheorem{Theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{Lemma}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{Corollary}{Corollary}
\newtheorem{Proposition}{Proposition}
\newtheorem{Algorithm}{Algorithm}
\numberwithin{Theorem}{section}
\numberwithin{Definition}{section}
\numberwithin{Lemma}{section}
\numberwithin{Algorithm}{section}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}


% *********************************************************************
% Headings and page layout
% *********************************************************************
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % to design my own headings
\usepackage{titlesec, titletoc} % to design my own toc and part/chapter/section styles

% page style of "chapter"
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\LARGE \bfseries}
    {\Large Chapter \thesection \thispagestyle{plain}}{0ex}{\titlerule\vspace{2ex}}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0ex}{-8ex}{8ex}

\titleformat{\section}[display]{\LARGE \bfseries}
    {\thispagestyle{plain}}{0ex}{\titlerule\vspace{2ex}}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0ex}{0ex}{0ex}

\titleformat{\subsection}[display]{\Large \bfseries}
    {\thispagestyle{plain}}{0ex}{\vspace{2ex}}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0ex}{0ex}{3ex}


% definition of headings
\fancypagestyle{memo}{
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[RO,LE]{\thepage}
    \fancyhead[RE]{\rightmark}
    \fancyhead[LO]{\leftmark}
    \renewcommand\headrulewidth{0.5pt}
}


\begin{document}
As a part of the programme mentioned above, delivery models are designed to meet the needs of each group. The table below summarises their delivery model.
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{Delivery model} 
\centering
\renewcommand\cellalign{lc}
\setcellgapes{3pt}
\makegapedcells
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|l|}
  \hline 
  \textbf{JCVI Priority} &
  \textbf{Deployment strategy} &
  \textbf{Estimated finishing date} \\
  \hline
  1 and 2 &
  \makecell{Care home residents and staff: Resident homes \\
    Over 80 years old: GP surgeries } &
  5th Februrary 2021 \\
  3,4 and 5 &
  Vaccination appointment & Early March 2021 \\ 
  6,7,8 and 9 &
  Mass vaccination centres & Early May 2021 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
%\vspace{-3mm}  %% <------
\end{table}
The indicates that the vaccinations began in Scotland on 8 January
2021. However, whether the vaccination process began all across
Scotland.

\end{document}
```

Comment: I dont know what is happening. When I post the same code to a different tex file, this works as desired, but it does not work in my latex file.

Comment: The only difference between your tex file and mine is that `\vspace{-3mm}`.